# get criteria values from FilterBuilder

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I want to get values of `filterBuilder.getCriteria()` field name and value

```
final FilterBuilder filterBuilder = new FilterBuilder();

filterBuilder.setDataSource(a.getInstance());


IButton filterButton = new IButton("Filter");
filterButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

        // i want to get values of filterBuilder.getCriteria()
        //field name and value

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is what you are looking for, but from the javadoc of SmartGWT
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/FilterBuilder.html#getCriteria()

And looking at AdvancedCriteria method getValues() i think we might do this way. http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/Criteria.html#getValues()

```
final FilterBuilder filterBuilder = new FilterBuilder();

filterBuilder.setDataSource(a.getInstance());

IButton filterButton = new IButton("Filter");
filterButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
@Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

    //field name and value
    Map criteria = filterBuilder.getCriteria().getValues();


 }
});
```

Comment: but i need to extract fields name , and values from this values

Comment: What do you mean? criteria.keySet() and criteria.values() methods of hashmap  cant be used?